# is there a shorter way to write: *((T*)(v.addr))=value;

Tags: c++

I have a template function with

```
template <typename T>
```

somewhere else is defined:

```
void* v.addr;
```

I need to simplify `*((T*)(v.addr))=value;`

I thought it could be: `(T&)(v.addr)=value;` but as I read in stack overflow it doesn't work.
Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, casts are ugly. Yes that is intentional. (Also, for `void*`, please use `static_cast`)

Comment: @MikeSeymour You can't dereference a `void *`, unfortunately.

Comment: @T.C.: Of course you can't. That was a silly suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much you can do with that expression except to remove the extraneous parentheses:

```
*(T *)v.addr = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your type `v` and add a:

```
template_typename T>
T& get_addr() const{ return *static_cast<T*>(addr); }
```

then invoke:

```
v.get_addr<T>() = value;
```

which moves the ugly casts into one spot (and makes them more explicit).